# Insert JSON formatted string into JSON structure

Tags: json, string, json.net

I have a question about inserting a json formatted string into a json structure and having the final version be a combined JSON formatted string that can be serialized into a JSON structure.  I am using the newtonsofts Json.NET

I have the following JSON structure:

```
public class ResponseJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "header")]
    public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "results")]
    public string responseResults { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseHeader
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]
    public string version { get; set; }
}
```

In the code, I do the following:

```
        ResponseJson responseJson = new ResponseJson();
        responseJson.responseHeader = new ResponseHeader()
        {
            name = A_NAME,
            version = A_VERSION
        };
        responseJson.responseResults = resultJson;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

resultJson is a properly formatted JSON string (in this case, an array of objects, but could be anything JSON formatted).  Right now, if i execute the code, I get the following (which is expected, since "results" is declared as a string):

```
{
    "header":
        {
            "name":"abcd",
            "version":"1.0"
        },
    "results":
        "[{\"data\":{\"level\":\"100\"},\"code\":{\"value\":\"JBC\",\"type\":\"ev\"},\"time\":{\"start\":\"20\",\"end\":\"101\"}}]"
}
```

what I do need as an output is:

```
{
    "header":
        {
            "name":"abcd",
            "version":"1.0"
        },
    "results":
        [
            {
                "data":
                    {
                        "level":"100"
                    },
                "code":
                    {
                        "value":"JBC",
                        "type":"ev"
                    },
                "time":
                    {
                        "start":"20",
                        "end":"101"
                    }
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  In the line`responseJson.responseResults = resultJson` the variable `resultJson` is undefined.  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: type string.  thank you

Comment: so, you need to do the opposite of what your title asks for, because you are currently correctly inserting a json string into another json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't explain how you create your `resultJson` variable, it's implied from your code that you are double-serializing your results: you compute an array of "result" classes, serialize them to a JSON string, store the string in your `ResponseJson` class, and them serialize that in turn.  The embedded JSON string then gets escaped as per the JSON standard, which is what you are seeing.

You need to avoid double-serializing your data, for instance by using the following data model:

```
public class ResponseJson<T>
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "header")]
    public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "results")]
    public T responseResults { get; set; }
}

public static class ResponseJson
{
    public static ResponseJson<T> Create<T>(T responseResults, ResponseHeader responseHeader)
    {
        return new ResponseJson<T> { responseResults = responseResults, responseHeader = responseHeader };
    }
}

public class ResponseHeader
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]
    public string version { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would do:

```
        var results = GetResults(); // Get your result data
        var responseJson = ResponseJson.Create(results, new ResponseHeader()
        {
            name = A_NAME,
            version = A_VERSION
        });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

If for whatever reason you *must* embed a previously serialized JSON string as JSON rather than as a string literal, you'll need to re-parse it back to a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm):

```
        string resultJson = GetResultJson(); // Get result json string.
        var responseJson = ResponseJson.Create(JToken.Parse(resultJson), new ResponseHeader()
        {
            name = A_NAME,
            version = A_VERSION
        });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Json.NET will include the `JToken` in your outer JSON as nested JSON rather than as a string literal.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  I suppose that I should have made it clearer that i cant assume what the format of 'resultJson' (or 'results' as you called it) will be.  all I can assume is that its a properly formatted JSON string.  Your solution requires me to know what it is.  I will make an update to my original equestion

Comment: @concentriq - I modified the solution so that `responseResults` can be implicitly typed.  Or do you have some code constraint that *requires* that `responseResults` was previously serialized as JSON?

Comment: "re-parse it back to a JToken" is the answer I was looking for in this situation.  string is all i have to work with here.